# Scrolling to bottom when keyboard shows up

Tags: scroll, keyboard, ionic-framework

I have a registration form in my ionic app that contains several fields, so it needs to be scrollable. Becuse the elements sizes are set as a percentage of the screen height, I set `<preference name="Fullscreen" value="true" />` on the `config.xml`. If I didn't do that, the elements heights would resize every time the keyboard shows up.

However, the view doesn't scroll up to the submit bottom (at the bottom) when the keyboard is active, so there are some fields that lay under the keyboard.

How can I avoid that and allow the form to scroll to the end even when the keyboard is active?

Comment: I posted an answer to the similar question that could help you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34355865/1630623

Answer (score 0):

you can  use the **scrollDelegate** to scroll bottom or top check this link out

http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/