# Form Input/Keyboard on Orientation Change ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm using ionic and When I change the phone orientation in a form input I want to get just an input place

Comment: you want the form input field to be focused ?? did I get you right ??

Comment: When i focus on an input field, the soft keyboard pops up and for certain fields, according to their position, it gets on top of it i.e the keyboard hides the input fields. "in full screen "

Comment: check this link out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898538/ionic-framework-keyboard-hides-input-field